# Double slashes in url with redirect_url of multisafe

Tags: php, symfony

payment is working, when it is redirecting it back, then it is displaying like,

http://www.test.com//bedankt/?transactionid=979

Due to double slashes it is going 404 error, **when i remove one slash page is loading properly.**

while in the code, i have used the standard way of declaration,

```
include(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/multisafepay.php');
    $msp = new MultiSafepay();

    $msp->merchant['account_id']       = MSP_ACCOUNT_ID;
    $msp->merchant['site_id']          = MSP_SITE_ID;
    $msp->merchant['site_code']        = MSP_SITE_CODE;
    $msp->merchant['redirect_url']     = BASE_URL.'bedankt/';
```

Comment: **http://www.test.com//bedankt/?transactionid=979** , this url is demo, site is on test server.  you can notice the double slashes after www.test.com, the domain is different on which the site is located, can't share the domain name.

Comment: check BASE_URL. what you are getting in this constant ?

Comment: it is giving like, **http://www.test.com/** and i think it is ok.

Comment: You could always do `str_replace(array('//', ':/'), array('/', '://'), $msp->merchant['redirect_url']);` to remove double slashes (and make sure you add one back in front of `http`).  This is definitely not ideal though, I would check your `BASE_URL` constant.

Comment: the problem is with the double slash after domain name, i.e. test.com   i have also tried rtrim(BASE_URL,'/'), but not working.

Comment: Where is this url generated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do:

```
$msp->merchant['redirect_url']     = rtrim(BASE_URL,'/').'bedankt/';
```

If you are, you should search elsewhere if the url is not genrated by another code, in test file, for instance.